# Cannot create stored procedure with sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, stored-procedures, sequelize.js

I am running the following SQL query:

```
Executing (default): DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS x;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE x()
BEGIN
    # do something
END $$
DELIMITER; $$
```

Like so:

```
sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```

But I get this error (even though it works just fine, if I use any other SQL client):

> SequelizeDatabaseError:
>   ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE x()
>
> BEGIN

I already added `multipleStatements = true` to my connection config, but it does not do anything.

**Update**

I ended up using `RAW` instead, like so:

```
sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
});
```

Comment: Did you add `multipleStatements` to `sequelize.options.dialectOptions`?

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier I have, and I even added a check to my `mysql/lib/ConnectionConfig.js`, and verified that `options.multipleStatements` is actually true. However, I realized later that it worked on a friend's machine just fine, so I assume that it is a bug in my MySQL connector. Will let you know, when I have any updates...

Comment: @Domi，Any further update?

Comment: @huangchang Can't quite remember. I think I ended up using `sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW });`

Answer (score 5):

`DELIMITER` is not part of *MySQL server*, it's part of the *MySQL command line client*. This feature is not available in the driver.

Source: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/280#issuecomment-8081626

Answer (score 2):

Your error is actually in the last line. Take out the `$$` after `DELIMITER;`
The statement: `DELIMITER;` resets the delimiter to `;` the `$$` after that confuses the syntax analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue as well in Sequelize with MySQL. The solution that worked for me was **removing** both the `DELIMITER` statements. This would make the original posters procedure look like this:

```js
const query = `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS x;

CREATE PROCEDURE x()
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
    SELECT 2;
END;`

await sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
});
```

As this [Github comment suggested](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/619#issuecomment-26628140), not only is `DELIMITER` not available to the Node.js MySQL client, it's **not necessary**, since Node.js client uses quotes or backticks to determine where your query ends, and uses the `BEGIN` and `END` tokens to determine where the trigger code begins and ends.